# How can I pretty-print a struct with its fields being named?

Tags: c++, reflection, pretty-print

Suppose I have a

```
struct foo { int bar; double baz; };
```

And a `struct foo s;` somewhere. I would like to be able to write `magic(s)` and get a string, or text printed to cout, which includes not just the values of s.bar and s.baz, but also the identifiers 'bar' and 'baz'.

I know C++ doesn't have proper reflection, but maybe something RTTIish (I'm not well-versed in RTTI)? Or perhaps with some minor decoration of the class declaration?

Note: Of course I'm asking about a solution which would work for any type, or at least any struct; obviously I can implement an `operator<<` for `foo`'s.

Comment: variable names are not present in the binary. You'll need something much more extensive, IMHO.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: 1. I was talking about field names, not variable names, and also 2. You're right, but a binary might have debug symbols; or other kinds of instrumentation.

Comment: Also, this is most likely a case where a solution (if it exists) will differ between C and C++. Remove one of the tags.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Yes, I suppose you're right.

Comment: Unfortunately, most reflection features are not yet standardized, but it is interesting to note that the current reflection proposal for C++1z does allow you to iterate over class members.

Comment: Are you open to using 3rd party reflection libraries?

Comment: write a script that reads in your class files and dumps a print method into the definition somewhere.

Comment: @KABoissonneault: So you're saying "wait 2 years and you'll have your answer". Might not be such a bad option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may well have to wait until C++ get reflection facilities added to the language.

This is being actively worked on, by WG21 SG7. What's that? [WG21](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee) is the working group of the [International Standards Organization](http://www.iso.org/iso/home.html) (ISO) which develops the C++ language standards. SG7 is the sub-group in charge of exploring the possibilities reflection.

SG7 has a [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/reflection) in which it discusses its ongoing work.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(
        std::ostream& os, // stream object
        const foo& f
    )
    {
        os << /*ToDo - nice formatting of data members*/
        return os;
    }
```

Then this will work with `cout` etc:

`foo f; cout << "My foo is " << f << ".";`

Comment: Obviously I don't want to implement that for every possible type I have declared...

Comment: Obviously? How many types do you need this for?! You have to implement the equivalent in Java yourself too.

Comment: How many? All of them. And the whole point is not writing this code.

Comment: Well, 1. do it my way, 2. change to Java, 3. Build a custom build step that generates the code automatically.

Comment: @einpoklum correction on Bathsheba's point about Java — you can rather switch to Rust. It's the new C++, and there is a way to print structs.